# How to readjust mxgraph edges while moving vertices to not look weird?

Tags: angular, typescript, edges, vertices, mxgraph

I need to allow users to rearrange a graph and need to re-adjust the edges when they move vertices. Right now I was not yet able to nicely do it.

What I have so far is this:

**Graph with edges weirdly adjusted:**

[image: Graph with edges weirdly adjusted]

But I would like them to be like this:

**Graph with edges nicely adjusted:**

[image: Graph with edges nicely adjusted]

The XML code to the second diagram is that:

```xml
    <mxGraphModel dx="774" dy="824" grid="1" gridSize="10" guides="1" tooltips="1" connect="1" arrows="1" fold="1" page="1" pageScale="1" pageWidth="850" pageHeight="1100">
      <root>
        <mxCell id="0"/>
        <mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>
        <mxCell id="4" value="" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;startArrow=classic;startFill=1;targetPerimeterSpacing=8;sourcePerimeterSpacing=8;strokeColor=#aaaaaa;strokeWidth=2;curved=1;" edge="1" parent="1" source="2" target="3">
          <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="2" value="Product" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;fillColor=#f8b241;gradientColor=#e97704;gradientDirection=south;fontStyle=1;fontColor=#FFFFFF;strokeColor=#ea7703;" vertex="1" parent="1">
          <mxGeometry x="80" y="33" width="116" height="26" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="6" value="" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;startArrow=classic;startFill=1;targetPerimeterSpacing=8;sourcePerimeterSpacing=8;strokeColor=#aaaaaa;strokeWidth=2;curved=1;" edge="1" parent="1" source="3" target="5">
          <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="10" value="" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;startArrow=classic;startFill=1;targetPerimeterSpacing=8;sourcePerimeterSpacing=8;strokeColor=#aaaaaa;strokeWidth=2;curved=1;" edge="1" parent="1" source="3" target="9">
          <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="3" value="Order_line" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;fillColor=#f8b241;gradientColor=#e97704;gradientDirection=south;fontStyle=1;fontColor=#FFFFFF;strokeColor=#ea7703;" vertex="1" parent="1">
          <mxGeometry x="280" y="216" width="116" height="26" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="12" value="" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;startArrow=classic;startFill=1;targetPerimeterSpacing=8;sourcePerimeterSpacing=8;strokeColor=#aaaaaa;strokeWidth=2;curved=1;" edge="1" parent="1" source="9" target="11">
          <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="9" value="New_1" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;fillColor=#f8b241;gradientColor=#e97704;gradientDirection=south;fontStyle=1;fontColor=#FFFFFF;strokeColor=#ea7703;" vertex="1" parent="1">
          <mxGeometry x="460" y="190" width="116" height="26" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="14" value="" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;startArrow=classic;startFill=1;targetPerimeterSpacing=8;sourcePerimeterSpacing=8;strokeColor=#aaaaaa;strokeWidth=2;curved=1;" edge="1" parent="1" source="11" target="13">
          <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="11" value="New_2" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;fillColor=#f8b241;gradientColor=#e97704;gradientDirection=south;fontStyle=1;fontColor=#FFFFFF;strokeColor=#ea7703;" vertex="1" parent="1">
          <mxGeometry x="530" y="20" width="116" height="26" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="13" value="New_3" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;fillColor=#f8b241;gradientColor=#e97704;gradientDirection=south;fontStyle=1;fontColor=#FFFFFF;strokeColor=#ea7703;" vertex="1" parent="1">
          <mxGeometry x="680" y="126" width="116" height="26" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="8" value="" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;startArrow=classic;startFill=1;targetPerimeterSpacing=8;sourcePerimeterSpacing=8;strokeColor=#aaaaaa;strokeWidth=2;curved=1;" edge="1" parent="1" source="5" target="7">
          <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="5" value="Order" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;fillColor=#f8b241;gradientColor=#e97704;gradientDirection=south;fontStyle=1;fontColor=#FFFFFF;strokeColor=#ea7703;" vertex="1" parent="1">
          <mxGeometry x="80" y="100" width="116" height="26" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="7" value="Customer" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;fillColor=#f8b241;gradientColor=#e97704;gradientDirection=south;fontStyle=1;fontColor=#FFFFFF;strokeColor=#ea7703;" vertex="1" parent="1">
          <mxGeometry x="10" y="260" width="116" height="26" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
      </root>
    </mxGraphModel>
```

But I am not being able to translate this in TS code :-(

Since I am using it with Angular and TS it is a little tricky to create something in Plunker to help, but what I have is a component that initializes the graph like that:

```js
    declare var require: any;

    const mx = require('mxgraph')({
      mxImageBasePath: 'assets/mxgraph/images',
      mxBasePath: 'assets/mxgraph',
    });


    const container = document.getElementById('graphContainer');
    this.graph = new mx.mxGraph(container);

So I start editing it, as you can see here:

    try {
      const parent = this.graph.getDefaultParent();
      this.graph.getModel().beginUpdate();

      const defaultVertexStyle = this.graph.stylesheet.getDefaultVertexStyle();
      defaultVertexStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE] = mx.mxConstants.SHAPE_LABEL;
      defaultVertexStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_PERIMETER] = mx.mxConstants.PERIMETER_RECTANGLE;
      defaultVertexStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_FONTSIZE] = 12;
      defaultVertexStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_FONTFAMILY] = 'Helvetica';
      defaultVertexStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_ALIGN] = mx.mxConstants.ALIGN_CENTER;
      defaultVertexStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_VERTICAL_ALIGN] = mx.mxConstants.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
      defaultVertexStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_FILLCOLOR] = '#f8b241';
      defaultVertexStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_GRADIENTCOLOR] = '#e97704';
      defaultVertexStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR] = '#ea7703';
      defaultVertexStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_FONTCOLOR] = '#ffffff';
      defaultVertexStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_FONTSIZE] = 14;
      defaultVertexStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_ROUNDED] = true;

      const defaultEdgeStyle = this.graph.stylesheet.getDefaultEdgeStyle();
      defaultEdgeStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE] = mx.mxConstants.SHAPE_CONNECTOR;
      defaultEdgeStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_FONTSIZE] = 12;
      defaultEdgeStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_FONTFAMILY] = 'Helvetica';
      defaultEdgeStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_ALIGN] = mx.mxConstants.ALIGN_CENTER;
      defaultEdgeStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_VERTICAL_ALIGN] = mx.mxConstants.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
      defaultEdgeStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_ROUNDED] = 1;
      defaultEdgeStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_STARTARROW] = mx.mxConstants.ARROW_CLASSIC;
      defaultEdgeStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_STARTSIZE] = 8;
      defaultEdgeStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_ENDARROW] = mx.mxConstants.ARROW_CLASSIC;
      defaultEdgeStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_ENDSIZE] = 8;
      defaultEdgeStyle[mx.mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR] = '#aaaaaa';

      let product = graph.insertVertex(parent,'Product','Product',0,0,120,20);
      let orderLine = graph.insertVertex(parent,'Order_Line','Order_Line',0,0,120,20);
      let order = graph.insertVertex(parent,'Order','Order',0,0,120,20);
      let customer = graph.insertVertex(parent,'Customer','Customer',0,0,120,20);
      let new1 = graph.insertVertex(parent,'new1','new1',0,0,120,20);

      graph.insertEdge(parent, '1', '', product, orderLine);
      graph.insertEdge(parent, '2', '', orderLine, order);
      graph.insertEdge(parent, '3', '', order, customer);
      graph.insertEdge(parent, '4', '', orderLine, new1);

      const layout = new mx.mxHierarchicalLayout(this.graph, mx.mxConstants.DIRECTION_NORTH);
      layout.execute(graph.getDefaultParent());
    } finally {
      this.graph.getModel().endUpdate();
    }
```

And the result is what you see in the first picture above. ([Graph with edges weirdly adjusted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZJ6H.png))

Can you help me to achieve what we can see in the second picture ([Graph with edges nicely adjusted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAalQ.png)), please?

**Edit 1:**
Unfortunately, even if I use the same style we have in the XML file, it is not rearranging the edges like in the demo/showcase, I have tried it already:

```js
graph.insertEdge(
                parent,
                `${getId()}`,
                '',
                source,
                target, 
 'edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;startArrow=classic;startFill=1;targetPerimeterSpacing=8;sourcePerimeterSpacing=8;strokeColor=#aaaaaa;strokeWidth=2;curved=1;'
              );
```

Result:
[image: Even using styles as in XML the result is different]

**Edit 2:**

Although it hasn't worked on my code, on this CodePen it is working: https://codepen.io/palerique/pen/povEEVY

So now I think that this layout class I am calling can be changing the style and causing this undesired behavior.

Is there a layout class that don't change the edges style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PauloRodrigues
Funny, but your decision is already in question!

Just [insertEdge](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.insertEdge) with this param for style 
`edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;startArrow=classic;startFill=1;targetPerimeterSpacing=8;sourcePerimeterSpacing=8;strokeColor=#aaaaaa;strokeWidth=2;curved=1;`

Call `insertEdge(parent,id,value,source,target, yourStyle)`

It will be like:
`graph.insertEdge(parent, null, '', mxCell, mxCell,'edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;startArrow=classic;startFill=1;targetPerimeterSpacing=8;sourcePerimeterSpacing=8;strokeColor=#aaaaaa;strokeWidth=2;curved=1;');`

Answer (score 0):

you should realize custom edges paintEdgeShape defines the rendering of the edge, you use the [canvas API](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/util/mxAbstractCanvas2D-js.html#mxAbstractCanvas2D.curveTo) to define that drawing. Look [example](https://codepen.io/bohdan-skochko/pen/QWwKLaw).

To solve long path I will recommend to create function that calculate nearest path between points and draw.

```
                NewShape.prototype.paintEdgeShape = function(c, pts)
                {
                    // calculate nearest path and draw
                };
```

Comment: I am afraid your example is too advanced...

Since my desired behavior is the one here on the demo/showcase graph editor - https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html - I thought we have some already developed feature that allows me to have this behavior.

Do you know if it is already there? Thank you so much!

Comment: @PauloRodrigues Did you check another my answer?